# KDE randomly locks screen

Tags: 12.04, kde, lock-screen, lock

I have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and I installed the KDE desktop via the `sudo apt-get install kde-plasma-desktop` command (I wanted less stuff than the `sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop` command would install). 
I did a bit of tweaking (changing the order of the buttons/messing with decorations & themes, nothing terribly internal). For some reason, KDE will randomly lock the screen. Is this a problem with Ubuntu, KDE, a KDE theme, or what?

This isn't a gargantuan problem as I prefer LXDE and will be using it (it runs fine the way I want it), so if you're working on and about to find the cure for cancer, don't drop that to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wiped 12.04 LTS and installed 13.04 over it, and I am loving it. Nice and speedy compared to my previous installation, and almost none of the glitches. That also solved this problem so I am answering my own and marking as such to close the question.